# How to group by in Entity Framework Core with no repetitive group?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, linq, .net-core

I want to perform a group by in Entity Framework core with no repetitive groups.

Lets suppose I have two columns

```
Column A     Column B
1            1
2            1
2            1
4            5
5            4
```

If a group by is performed for two columns Entity framework core the result is pretty obvious.

```
Column A     Column B
1            1
2            1
4            5
5            4
```

But i want to perform a group by which works both ways A->B and B->A hence the result would be

```
Column A     Column B
1            1
2            1
5            4
```

Any idea how to do that in Entity Framework Core?

My original attempt was to use Union

```
 var user = _context.Transactions
        .Where(p => !p.IsDeleted && (p.ReceiverUserId == userId) &&
                    (p.SenderUserId != null))
        .Include(p => p.SenderUser)
        .GroupBy(p => p.SenderUserId)
        .Select(p => new TempModel { Id = p.FirstOrDefault().SenderUser.Id, User = p.FirstOrDefault().SenderUser, CreatedDate = p.FirstOrDefault().CreatedDate });

    var user2 = _context.Transactions
        .Where(p => !p.IsDeleted && (p.SenderUserId == userId) &&
                    (p.ReceiverUserId != null))
        .Include(p => p.ReceiverUser)
        .GroupBy(p => p.ReceiverUserId)
        .Select(p => new TempModel { Id = p.FirstOrDefault().ReceiverUser.Id, User = p.FirstOrDefault().ReceiverUser, CreatedDate = p.FirstOrDefault().CreatedDate});

    var finalQuery = user.Union(user2);
    var finalQuery2 = finalQuery.GroupBy(p => p.Id);
    var finalQuery1 = finalQuery2.OrderByDescending(p => p.FirstOrDefault().CreatedDate);


finalQuery.GroupBy(p => p.Id); <- this line gives error
```

Comment: How simplified is this scenario? Is calling `Distinct()` enough for your needs?

Comment: my first approach was using distinct but that didn't help.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far then? The actual queries?

Comment: My original queries involve one single table. where should I send you as the example here is different from the actual queries

Comment: Updated question

Answer (score 0):

You should sort these columns by descending: `4-5 => 5-4;` `5-4 => 5-4;`
`5-5 => 5-5` and then `group by` or `distinc` by them:

```
var answer = db.Table.Select(x => new 
{                 
    ColumnA = x.ColumnA > x.ColumnB ? x.ColumnA : x.ColumnB,
    ColumnB = x.ColumnA > x.ColumnB ? x.ColumnB : x.ColumnA
}).Distinct().ToList();
```